# Visually map the contents of my Google Drive

Tags: file-management, data-visualization, charts, google-drive

I'm a fairly avid Google Drive user with hundreds of folders and files on drive.

However I find it difficult to stay organized sometimes and get a broader view of the state/organizational structure of my resources on the network.

How can I generate a map/hierarchal chart of all my folders/documents on the network?

Comment: Can you sketch something to show what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Any basic hierarchal representation should suffice. i.e.: 
https://www.google.ca/search?q=hierarchy+tree&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=949&tbm=isch&imgil=nA2xtAXs_hfXQM%253A%253BscDMkwdB77uUqM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fdownload.oracle.com%25252Fotn_hosted_doc%25252Fjdeveloper%25252F1012%25252Fuixapps%25252Fhtmlhelp%25252Fcreateui%25252Fadd%25252Fnavigation%25252Fuix_auitreestrucdata.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=nA2xtAXs_hfXQM%253A%252CscDMkwdB77uUqM%252C_&usg=__T6TkdSGekLtpBerBqK03K-x5Llo%3D&ved=0ahUKEwif7LqRmLjPAhVh6YMKHZoSCQQQyjcIMg&ei=re3uV9_hJuHSjwSapaQg#imgrc=nA2xtAXs_hfXQM%3A

Comment: What OS are you using? Is generating something from the command line ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your Google Drive files with a local directory using [Backup and Sync](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?), and then you can use [WizTree](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/) or [alternatives for other operating systems](https://alternativeto.net/software/wiztree/) to see a directory tree and a [treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) (see screenshots on [the WizTree website](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/)).

Answer (score 0):

You could connect your Google Drive with a Linux desktop and then use the `tree` command to visually map the whole thing! And then use `grep` and such tools to filter down the tree!